# Is radiation pressure a doppler effect?

Tags: doppler-effect, radiation-pressure

I came to this conclusion for the following reasons (thanks to the people who answered my recent questions):

- A photon pushing a mirror(*) loses energy in the form of a red shift (*through radiation pressure and total reflection);
- Pushing a mirror against a photon makes it gain energy in the form of a blue shift.

Regarding radiation pressure, the typical explanation is that reflection makes the photon loses energy because it gives some to the mirror. However my guess is that there is no causality direction here and one could also say that the photon gets red shifted because the mirror moved apart during the collision (as would be described a doppler effect, thus my question).

What is your opinion?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First of all, there is always a reference frame in which the photon does not lose energy.

That being said, the only constraint is that the momentum transfer from the photon to the mirror has to be orthogonal to the 4-velocity of the mirror.

So if we work along the $z$-axis, with:

$$ p^f_{\mu} = (k, 0, 0, k) $$

and

$$ p^f_{\mu} = (k', 0, 0, -k) $$

with  momentum transfer:

$$ q_{\mu} = p^f_{\mu}- p^i_{\mu} = -(k-k',0, 0, k+k')$$

Ensuring that that is orthogonal to a mirror with any four momentum (and a mass $M\gg k $), will give you the (two way) relativistic doppler shift.

For example, if the mirror has 4-velocity:

$$ u_{\mu} = \gamma(c, 0, 0, v) $$

then:

$$ q^{\mu}u_{\mu} = -\gamma[(k-k')c - (k+k')v] = 0$$

implies

$$(k-k')c  = (k+k')v $$

The ratio of received (Rx) to transmitted (Tx) frequency ($f=\frac{ck}{2\pi}$) is:

$$ \frac{f_{Rx}
}{f_{Tx}} = \frac{k'}k = \frac{1-\frac v c}{1+\frac v c} = \sqrt{ \frac{1-\frac v c}{1+\frac v c}} \sqrt{ \frac{1-\frac v c}{1+\frac v c}}$$

The first factor, which is the standard relativity doppler shift, is because the mirror is receding from the transmitter, and the second factor is because the mirror (new source) is receding from the receiver (formerly, the transmitter).

Comment: So radiation pressure can be interpreted as a doppler effect? (this is the question)

Answer (score 1):

A typical explanation of radiation pressure does not have a photon losing any energy. It is simply a consequence of a particle bouncing normally off a mirror transferring twice its momentum to the mirror.

I don't see the distinction between that and the calculation of ideal gas pressure, which assumes elastic collisions with any containing walls.

Physics is full of such approximations. For example we rarely consider an object falling to Earth in terms of *both* the object and the Earth accelerating in the centre of mass frame.

Comment: Sorry but not the point. Here I assume there is energy to set the mirror in motion and it has to come from somewhere. There is no mystery, it comes from the incident light. Now my question is rather if there is fundamentally a difference between the radiation pressure with no absorption, and doppler.